# Python: keep open browser in pyppeteer and create CDPSession

Tags: python, pyppeteer

I've got two issues that I can't solve it at them moment.

**1.** I would like to keep the browser running so I could just re-connect using [`pyppeteer.launcher.connect()`](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.launcher.connect) function but it seems to be closed imidiately even if I don't call [`pyppeteer.browser.Browser.close()`](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.browser.Browser.close).

**test01.py:**

```
import asyncio

from pyppeteer import launch, connect

async def fetch():
    browser = await launch(
        headless=False,
        args=['--no-sandbox']
    )
    print(f'Endpoint: {browser.wsEndpoint}')
    await browser.disconnect()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fetch())

$ python test01.py
Endpoint: ws://127.0.0.1:51757/devtools/browser/00e917a9-c031-499a-a8ee-ca4090ebd3fe
$ curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" http://127.0.0.1:51757
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 51757: Connection refused
```

**2.** How do I create CDP session. This code should open another browser window but it doesn't work as expected:

**test02.py**

```
import asyncio
import time

from pyppeteer import launch, connect

async def fetch():
    browser = await launch(
        headless=False,
        args=['--no-sandbox']
    )
    page = await browser.newPage()
    cdp = await page.target.createCDPSession()
    await cdp.send('Target.createBrowserContext')
    time.sleep(5)
    await browser.disconnect()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fetch())

$ python test02.py
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.',)>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How to keep the browser running

You just need to use `autoClose` flag, here's the [docs](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#launcher):

> autoClose (bool): Automatically close browser process when script
>   completed. Defaults to True.

In this case you **test01.py** would look as follows:

```
import asyncio

from pyppeteer import launch, connect

async def fetch():
    browser = await launch(
        headless=False,
        args=['--no-sandbox'],
        autoClose=False
    )
    print(f'Endpoint: {browser.wsEndpoint}')
    await browser.disconnect()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fetch())
```

#### CDP session

Here it is:

```
import asyncio
import time

from pprint import pprint

from pyppeteer import launch, connect
from pyppeteer.browser import BrowserContext

async def fetch():
    browser = await launch(
        headless=False,
        args=['--no-sandbox'],
        autoClose=False
    )
    page = await browser.newPage()
    cdp = await page.target.createCDPSession()
    raw_context = await cdp.send('Target.createBrowserContext')
    pprint(raw_context)
    context = BrowserContext(browser, raw_context['browserContextId'])
    new_page = await context.newPage()
    await cdp.detach()
    await browser.disconnect()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fetch())
```

Inspired by [Browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/_modules/pyppeteer/browser.html#Browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext) from `pyppeteer` itself.
Notice creating additional sessions via CDP doesn't seem to be such a great idea because `browser._contexts` won't be updated and will become inconsistent. It's also likely that `Browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext` might fit your needs without resorting to CDP whatsoever